# Hiding todo's created with todonotes

Tags: todonotes

I'm currently working on a document in which I need to indicate things to be done in a draft version, and I'd like to produce a final version where todos are hidden. The `todonotes` package features a `disable` option which is supposed to achieve this; it does remove todos defined with the `\todo` command, but it fails on my custom commands like this one:

```
\newcommand{\minortodo}[2][]{\todo[color=green, #1]{#2}}
```

The final PDF's output when using `\minortodo[inline]{change this to that}` is exactly `[inline]change this to that`. How do I go about telling `todonotes` to hide these instances as well? (note: removing inline does not solve the problem).

**EDIT**: the following minimal working example (thanks for the suggestion) suggests that the problem has another origin; this works as expected (i.e. minor todo's disappear too):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}   
\newcommand{\minortodo}[2][]{\todo[color=magenta, #1]{#2}}
\begin{document}
    Here's some text.
    \todo[inline]{this todo goes away}
    \minortodo[inline]{this one too}
\end{document}
```

In my actual document, I use the `book` class and load the following packages, but adding them to the MWE still causes no problem. The actual source of my document is a markdown file processed with pandoc with no template of my own, so I guess I'll have to look into what pandoc inserts that yields this behaviour.

```
\usepackage{minitoc}\dominitoc  
\usepackage{dot2texi}           
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}           
\usepackage{tabulary}           
\usepackage{todonotes}          
\usepackage{varwidth}
```

Comment: This should work (not tried) `\newboolean{boolhidetodonotes} 
\setboolean{boolhidetodonotes}{false}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{boolhidetodonotes}}%
 {\renewcommand{\minortodo}[2][]{\relax}}%if bool=TRUE: makes \minortodo do nothing
 {}%else: do nothing`. Change `\setboolean{boolhidetodonotes}{false}` into `\setboolean{boolhidetodonotes}{true}` to make your `\minortodo` notes disappear.

Comment: On my machine it does remove also the note issued by the custom command in this very basic document: `\begin{document}text \todo{to do}\par more text \minortodo{more to do}\end{document}`

Comment: Can you please add a minimal working example that is properly showcasing the misbehaviour.

Answer (score 1):

My shortcomings in using `sed` are to blame, not `todonotes` or `pandoc`. In case it might be useful: I thought the following command would replace `\usepackage{todonotes}` with `\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}`, but `grep` showed me I was wrong:

```
$ sed s/\\usepackage{todonotes}/\\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}/ draftdoc.tex | grep todonotes
\Sepackage[disable]{todonotes}
```

As a result, the `\todo` commands were undefined (I still don't get how they were hidden and minor todos weren't though). This produces the right results (mind the additional quotes):

```
$ sed 's/\\usepackage{todonotes}/\\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}/' draftdoc.tex | grep todonotes
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
```

Comment: I wonder what would have happened had you deleted the `.aux` file and rerun.   And I'm surprised you didn't get any errors with `\Sepackage...` (or did you run with scrollmode?).  Another fixwould have been `sed s/usepackage{todonotes}/usepackage[disable]{todonotes}/` -- as you don't match on the start of the line, just ignore the `\` at the beginning of the command.